# NDSolve with a constant

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have a simple differential equation like this

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == A y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

where $A$ is a constant. *Mathematica* gives `y` as a function of `x`. Now I want to change the $A$ factor from 1 to 10. Then I want to find the solution y as a function of $A$ (`y[x, A]`) and finally integrate over

```
Integrate[y[x = x0, A], A]
```

Please help me know what to do.

Comment: Have a look at [ParametricNDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html).

Answer (score 1):

As b.gatessucks suggested you can use [ParametricNDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html), here is my attempt:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == A* y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, {A}]
Integrate[Evaluate[Table[y[x][A] /. sol, {x, 0, 30, 1}]], {A, 1, 10}]
```

I obtained:

{9., 2.45807, 1.26895, 0.899877, 0.722946, 0.61851, 0.549178,0.504711, 0.473531,      0.454667, 0.335436, 0.322742, 0.311984, 0.302738, 0.294694, 0.287624, 0.281356, 0.275755, 0.270717, 0.266158, 0.26201, 0.258218, 0.254737, 0.251528, 0.248559, 0.245804, 0.24324, 0.240846, 0.238605, 0.236504, 0.234528}